# req.cookies are not found when sending a post to a express server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

Hi I have got a problem with sending a post request to the mongodb to save data from react client app.

```js
app.post('/places', (req, res) => {
    const {token} = req.cookies;
    const {title, address, addedPhotos, description, extraInfo, checkIn, checkOut, maxGuests} = req.body;
    console.log(token)
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const placeDoc = await Place.create({
            owner: userData.id,
            title, address, addedPhotos, description, extraInfo, checkIn, checkOut, maxGuests
        })
        res.json(placeDoc)
    });
})
```

When I'm console logging the token it is undefined even if im setting it during the login request.

```js
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    const userDoc = await User.findOne({email})

    if (userDoc) {
        const isPasswordSame = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password)
        if (isPasswordSame) {
            jwt.sign({email: userDoc.email, id: userDoc._id, name: userDoc.name}, jwtSecret, {}, (err, token) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.cookie('token', token).json(userDoc)
            })
        } else {
            res.json('pass not ok')
        }
    } else {
        res.json('Not found ')
    }
})
```

Here is the response of the post request in the browser.

[image]

There is a function that handles the request on submit: the whole body of the request is correct but because of the jwt token is not found my server is crashing during this post.

```js
const addNewPlace = async (ev: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        ev.preventDefault()
        const placeData = {
            title,
            address,
            addedPhotos,
            description,
            perks,
            extraInfo,
            checkIn,
            checkOut,
            maxGuests,
        }
        await axios.post('/places', placeData)

        setRedirect('/account/places')
    }
```

The whole file for the server app can be found here: https://github.com/mcwojdzinski/booking-app/blob/main/booking-api/index.js

Connection between server and mongodb is not the case here, because login and registering on the site is working properly, and even the token is set on localstorage.

Comment: maybe it's caused by cache... you should clear the cache

Comment: Still doesnt work :/ I even restarted the whole application but, It didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the cookie to send back your token you need to enable axios credential in order to send cookie to your server:

```
const addNewPlace = async () => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const placeData = {
    title,
    address,
    addedPhotos,
    description,
    perks,
    extraInfo,
    checkIn,
    checkOut,
    maxGuests,
  };
  await axios.post("/places",  
    {
      placeData,
    },
    { withCredentials: true }. // enable crendential to send cookies if your cookies is indeed present.
  );
  setRedirect("/account/places");
};
```

EDIT: I update the login post request using async/await and give more setting on the cookie:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    try {
        const userDoc = await User.findOne({email})
    
        if(!userDoc) {
            return res.status(401).json({error: "Wrong user name or password"})
        }
    
        const isPasswordSame = await bcrypt.compare(password,  userDoc.password);
       
        if(!isPasswordSame) {
            return res.status(401).json({error: "Wrong user name or password"})
        }
    
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            {
                email: userDoc.email,
                id: userDoc._id, 
                name: userDoc.name
            }, 
            jwtSecret,
        );
    
        res.cookie("token", accessToken, {
            maxAge: 60000,  // 1 min test
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true, // true only for production, in dev mode should be false
            sameSite: "none" // only work if secure is true in production, allow cross-origin requests to send the cookie, in dev mode is "lax"
        })
        res.json(userDoc) ; 
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
```

Comment: I added 2 rules in the App.tsx file which are:

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:4000'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true. Are they not enough to prevent those behaviours? (edit) Even with adding those rule to the exact axios request still doesnt work

Comment: Oh i didnt see your setting in your repo... I update it in case you want to create a axios config, but looks like there is another issue, did you have the cookie as expected with the token on the client ?

Comment: Now I checked and i don't have one. But this is weird because i can easly register as a new user and log in into the new account. But the cookie it self is not creating. Maybe the problem is in the /login post? when im creating the cookie

Comment: You can log because you send back the user if the password match, the cookie part is not being check on your client as a log in user.
I update the answer to add cookie setting but since my code is different have a look first and do some test, keep you code just in case, btw your jwtSecret is exposed, this should be set in the env file...

Comment: It is working! But still the token is not shown in the application -> storage -> cookies

Comment: hm I think that's because I set httpOnly flag to true, the cookie is sent as an HTTP header and is accessible by the server, but it is not available to JavaScript running on the client-side.